# Is it possible to setup more than one value in a page level custom variable in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is it possible to setup more than one value in a page level custom variable in Google Analytics?

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'Tag','tag value1',3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'Tag','tag value2',3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not if you insist on using the same index (first parameter to setCustomvar) for multiple calls - this will simply overwrite the first value. You can use up to five page level vars if you choose a different index (from 1 to 5) for each.

And if you find that 5 vars are not enough (and you don't have 250 Grand for Analytics Premium) you can store a concatenated string (value1_value2_value3) in a single var and use regular expressions in the GA interface to match a substring in you filters or goal definitions.

Comment: it is not good, how can i track multi-valued attributes (like tags) on the single page as separate ones? any suggestions would be nice

Comment: You could use events. Google Analytics tracks up to 500 tracking calls per session (pageviews, events, custom var etc) so this would leave you some wiggle room. Then you can create segments or define event goals, depending on what you're trying to do.